# How do you sub in variables to a string in yaml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

This is my current parameter that I am working with for AWS Cloudformation.

`ScheduleExpression: "rate(5 minutes)"`

I want the "5" to be parameterized to a mapping I created by `!FindInMap [ QuiesceLambda, LambdaEvaluationPeriodMin ]`

This does not seem to work. Does anyone have any insight?
`ScheduleExpression: "rate(${!FindInMap [ QuiesceLambda, LambdaEvaluationPeriodMin ]} minutes)"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work using `!Join` and without the `${}`

```
ScheduleExpression: !Join ["rate (", !FindInMap [ QuiesceLambda, LambdaEvaluationPeriodMin ], " minutes)"]
```

I have not tested this, so you may need to tweak it a bit

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a mapping like

```
Mappings:
  AnyName:
    QuiesceLambda: 
       LambdaEvaluationPeriodMin: 5
```

To use 5 from the map and to define the string **rate(5 minutes)** you could use Join.

```
ScheduleExpression: !Join
                    - ''
                    - - 'rate('
                      - !FindInMap ['AnyName', 'QuiesceLambda', 'LambdaEvaluationPeriodMin']
                      - ' minutes)'
```

> **Note**: !FindInMap takes 3 arguments not 2.